# 24 volt DC motor, No drive belt attached to motor, motor pulses, when speed increased, attached a belt to dive a shaft. pulsing stopped?

Tags: motor, dc

Apologies in advance for my very basic explanation of the problem I have experienced, as I'm a very amateur hobbyist.

I have a project I am working on, which has a 230volt AC power supply wired to a 300Watt AC/DC converter AC220V 230V to 24DC 12.5A - 15A power switching Transformer.
Which is wired to a EM - 285 DC motor speed regulator. then wired to a 12/24v 20A, High torque electric motor DC 24volt 3000rpm 200 watts.
The electric motor has a pulley that with a drive belt, can be attached onto a pulley, that is on a drive shaft, which has a flywheel mounted on it.

First I did a test run of the set up with out the motor being attached to the dive shaft with the belt.
I turned on the speed controller very slowly and the shaft on the motor started turning slowly, but when I turned the speed up, the motor speed started pulsing, right up to full speed.
I turned it down to zero, and the motor stop spinning, I then again turned the speed controller to set the motor spinning at a slow speed, and again it turn over with no pulsing, but as soon as I turned the speed up, the motor started pulsing.

I then attached the dive belt from the motor to the drive shaft, turned on the speed controller so that the motor started to rotate very slowly, I slowly increased the speed, and there was know pulsing just a sooth acceleration, as I went from very slowly speed to high speed, and back down till zero, when it stopped rotating.

Can any one explain why the motor did not pulse when I increase the speed from very slow, to top speed, when the belt was attached?

Comment: Drew1815 - Hi, This question is a duplicate of [your previous question](/q/685438) which was "closed". We don't allow asking the same question again to bypass question closure, as that is the primary quality control mechanism here. Therefore this question has been closed as a duplicate of that one. || Some different closure reasons were chosen by the site members who voted to close that one. Overall it seems they could not find a clear design question, with enough detail & information, in that previous question. Please see [here](/help/closed-questions) & [here](/help/reopen-questions).